# How to slow down the disappearance of the the Bootstrap 5 Toast?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a toast element defined in HTML:

```
<div class="position-fixed top-0 start-50 translate-middle-x" style="z-index: 9999">
    <div id="errNeutralAlreadyExists" class="toast fade bg-solid-white"
         role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"
         data-bs-animation="true" data-bs-autohide="true" data-bs-delay="3000">
        <div class="toast-header">
            <strong class="me-auto js-toast-title">Toast Title</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body">
            Toast message goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works fine, but I want it to disappear slow, not just vanish.  I tried setting the appropriate class but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
.toast.hide {
  transition-duration: 1s;
 }
```

How can I make it disappear slowly?

```js
const toastTrigger = document.getElementById('liveToastBtn')
const toastLiveExample = document.getElementById('errNeutralAlreadyExists')

if (toastTrigger) {
  toastTrigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const toast = new bootstrap.Toast(toastLiveExample)

    toast.show()
  })
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="liveToastBtn">Show live toast</button>

<div class="position-fixed top-0 start-50 translate-middle-x" style="z-index: 9999">
  <div id="errNeutralAlreadyExists" class="toast fade bg-solid-white" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-bs-animation="true" data-bs-autohide="true" data-bs-delay="3000">
    <div class="toast-header">
      <strong class="me-auto js-toast-title">Toast Title</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
      Toast message goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: @blurfus That takes me one step closer as it does fade.  The problem is that `.fade` seems to apply to the toast appearing as well.  It now slowly fades in.  I only want it to fade away when disappearing.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to set the fade duration as an option. You could file a [feature request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues) asking for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some javascript that checks if it is going to be shown or not and applies the different css:

```
.fadeSlow {
      transition: opacity 1s ease-out !important;
}
```

It overwrites the default only when in is fading away.
This is the added js part:

```
toastLiveExample.addEventListener('hide.bs.toast', () => {
  $("#errNeutralAlreadyExists").addClass("fadeSlow");
})
toastLiveExample.addEventListener('show.bs.toast', () => {
  $("#errNeutralAlreadyExists").removeClass("fadeSlow");
})
```

You can change the fade out speed by editing the css. The default is `0.15s` so I changed it to `1s` just for the example.

Hope that helps!

```js
const toastTrigger = document.getElementById('liveToastBtn')
const toastLiveExample = document.getElementById('errNeutralAlreadyExists')

if (toastTrigger) {
  toastTrigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const toast = new bootstrap.Toast(toastLiveExample)
    toast.show();
  })
}
toastLiveExample.addEventListener('hide.bs.toast', () => {
  $("#errNeutralAlreadyExists").addClass("fadeSlow");
})
toastLiveExample.addEventListener('show.bs.toast', () => {
  $("#errNeutralAlreadyExists").removeClass("fadeSlow");
})
```

```css
.fadeSlow {
      transition: opacity 1s ease-out !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="liveToastBtn">Show live toast</button>

<div class="position-fixed top-0 start-50 translate-middle-x" style="z-index: 9999">
  <div id="errNeutralAlreadyExists" class="toast fade bg-solid-white" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-bs-animation="true" data-bs-autohide="true" data-bs-delay="3000">
    <div class="toast-header">
      <strong class="me-auto js-toast-title">Toast Title</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
      Toast message goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```